# LLVM issue with InitializeNativeTarget

Tags: gcc, mingw, llvm, jit

I am trying to implement JIT shader support in a 3D software.

I compiled llvm 3.4 with mingw-w64, with the following options:
--enable-targets=x86,x86_64 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32

My program compiles and links fine with llvm libs.

However, in the first test, InitializeNativeTarget() returns false.

- How can I know more about the error?
- Any idea why this happens? In every sample/tutorial found there is a simple call to InitializeNativeTarget() and not even a check of the result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is old, others might still be looking for an answer.
The issue in this case is simply that `InitializeNativeTarget` returns `true` on a failure and `false` on success. This can easily be seen from the source:

```
inline bool InitializeNativeTarget() {
  // If we have a native target, initialize it to ensure it is linked in.
#ifdef LLVM_NATIVE_TARGET
  LLVM_NATIVE_TARGETINFO();
  LLVM_NATIVE_TARGET();
  LLVM_NATIVE_TARGETMC();
  return false;
#else
  return true;
#endif
}
```